How to calculate clearance volume in internal combustion engine of a tractor?
To begin with, a tractor engine is provided to identify and calculate the terminologies associated with it. The bore diameter and stroke length is given as 15.84 cm and 8 cm respectively. Having calculated the piston displacement to be 1576.486 cm3, I am stuck with calculating the clearance volume without which I cannot find the cylinder volume nor the compression ratio. Is there a better way to approach it? 

So work out the volume of the combustion chamber in the cylinder head. One easy way is to have the valves closed, fill with water until level then pour into a measuring jug.

@SolarMike your solution is more practical than theoretical. Thank you anyway for your swift response. I need an improvised method.

That is an improvised method - you don't have the engineering drawings to get the data from there...

@SolarMike but your method is questionable. how do I fill the combustion chamber with water? From the open valve or what?

From a syringe, teacup, plastic bag - just about anything that holds water...

@SolarMike start with a known volume of liquid in a decanter... pour into cylinder ... then measure what's left in the decanter

@jsotola easy isn't it.

@jsotola it's not easy as you make it seems. An illustration or a video link would be much appreciated

you cannot calculate the clearance volume without knowing the shape of  the cylinder head and the shape of the top of the piston ... direct measurement would be the simplest approach ... is it a diesel engine?

@jsotola yes it's a diesel engine of a tractor.

For this method to work you need access to the top of the combustion chamber. I can't imagine what the usefulness of this information is, or why it isn't mentioned in the spec of the engine.

@GregLocock exactly my thoughts. Thus I've resolved to assume it to be an ideal diesel engine and to take ten percent of the swept volume or displacement volume. What do you think?

No, the compression ratio of a diesel engine is around 20, so 5%

@GregLocock then it's settled. Thanks

You cannot, without knowing the geometry of the cylinder and head.
A 10 cm stroke in a 100 cm cylinder would have negligible compression.  You can't get there from here unless you have the machine in hand and can measure it.

is it safe to say that the clearance volume is ten percent of the swept volume?

@MICHAELUMANDE no, it's based on the size of the cylinder and head.
